# Model binding like syntax for the property binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, metronic

I'm working on [Metronic Theme's Angular 6](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=angular%2Foverview#docs) project. It has below code. Can you tell me what is the functionality of `[(action)]="action"`. I know how to bind to input metadata (i.e. `@Input()`). We normally do like so

```
<m-login *ngIf="action === 'login'" [action]="action"></m-login>
```

But here it is different. It is like 2-way model binding. But we normally use this syntax for that `[(ngModel)]="model"`. Any clue?

*auth.component.html*

```
<m-login *ngIf="action === 'login'" [(action)]="action"></m-login>
```

*login.ts*

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @Output() actionChange = new Subject<string>();
    @Input() action: string;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The two-way binding syntax is really just syntactic sugar for a
>   property binding and an event binding. Angular desugars the binding
>   into this:

if your property name is `action`, you only need to name its corresponding `EventEmitter` to `actionChange` and do the banana-in-a-box syntax for the child component `[(action)] = "parentProperty"` and Angular takes care of the rest.

Comment: Is that mean do I need to follow this pattern there? e.g. `@Output()` name must be like  `actionChange` and  `@Input()` name must be `action` .

Comment: If I use like this `@Output() action2` and `@Input() action` hope then it won't work no?

Comment: yes it will be @Output() actionChange = new Subject<string>();

Comment: https://github.com/ruhuayan/ang6/blob/4839acddeae07cfa4f2e31548e6395c73fd46eb8/src/app/content/pages/auth/login/login.component.ts

Comment: Then naming is the key here no? i..e `actionChange` and `action`

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me what is the functionality of [(action)]="action"

This functionality is called **two-way data binding**

For more information: [Two Way Binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

> You often want to both display a data property and update that
>   property when the user makes changes.
>
> On the element side that takes a combination of setting a specific
>   element property and listening for an element change event.
>
> Angular offers a special two-way data binding syntax for this purpose,
>   [(x)]. The [(x)] syntax combines the brackets of property binding,
>   [x], with the parentheses of event binding, (x).